# Website is online but isn't responding to connection attemps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I am attempting to install SharePoint in a 3 tier farm using hyper-v

My farm hasn't been configured by wizard and when I try to create a new site Collection it creates successfully, except when I access it I get

> This page can’t be displayed

and website (mysite-collection) is online but isn't responding to connection attemps

Comment: Hi EdDiesel, check the SharePoint logs, you'll certainly find something interesting there.

Comment: I can't find anything and without the correlation ID it's a bit hard to pin Point Whats Wrong.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest that you refresh your page, open the last log file (with notepad++ if possible) and look for all logs with the level "unexpected") and check the lines. You can also take a look at the windows event logs, they're very helpful.

Comment: are you accessing the site from Server or PC? did you created the root level site colelction? is their any http error code?

Comment: I am accessing From the Server in the App Servereven when I use the Front End server I still get the same error